# Online folder ordering different than my PC?

Tags: 10.04, folder

The folders are shown online (by web browser) sorted by Capital letter first then by lower case. This is not the case with Nautilus 2.30.1. For example;

online:    Apple Frog Mat bean cool dog

nautilus:  Apple bean cool dog cool Frog Mat

This makes it difficult to cross reference.

Comment: Is this an ubuntu-one related question?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Ubuntu's version of Nautilus is intended to sort case-insensitive, contrary to most linux application defaults. A google search brought up a thread that I believe holds your solution:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=34699

> I have since done a lot of digging around... and found the real source of the problem.  Nautilus (and ls) uses the computer's LOCALE settings to determine how to sort file/directory listings, in particular, the LC_COLLATE variable. By default, and for whatever reason, Arch overrides the preferred language settings by inserting its own LC_COLLATE variable in /etc/profile:
>   export LC_COLLATE="C"
>   Simply commenting this one line and restarting the computer will set LC_COLLATE back to the encoding specified by LOCALE in /etc/rc.conf.  In my case, en_CA.utf8.
>   My files and directories are now sorted alphanumerically case-insensitive

In your case, I think you want LC_COLLATE="C" instead.

I also found this relevant askubuntu post:
[Nautilus sorts the Name-column "mysteriously". How can I change the collating sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10896/nautilus-sorts-the-name-column-mysteriously-how-can-i-change-the-collating-seq)