# Can Nautilus use correct lexicographic sort?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Nautilus by default uses some kind of "natural" sort order which appears to target a use case like this:

```
photo 1.jpg
photo 2.jpg
photo 10.jpg
```

I do not want this behavior. I want Nautilus to sort consistent with ls. In this example, I want it sorted:

```
photo 1.jpg
photo 10.jpg
photo 2.jpg
```

Can I do this in Nautilus? Where is the setting that controls this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known *feature* ??#!! (known since 2006), but to many [(myself included)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10896/nautilus-sorts-the-name-column-mysteriously-how-can-i-change-the-collating-seq/12838#12838), it is more of a bug; but it isn't a bug, because it works as intended, ie. it sorts numbers as integers, not as text strings...  To be kind to this issue, it is technically not a bug, but just a case of: *"limited sorting options"*.

Here is bugzilla page on this point: [Bug 355152 - Sorting by name doesn't work with digits](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355152).. 
A quote from that page: "*This is just wrong.  Any user intent is completely nuked by a strange sorting algorithm*" ... my sentiments, exactly.

This *default (only?)* sort algorithm is handy for some people (I assume), but it doesn't suit me, so I've learnt to live with it by simply adding leading 0's, as a matter of course...

.. Here is another well-intended (human??) but odd-ball sorting feature which could benefit from some *options*:  [Nautilus: Copy file to same directory gives a whacky sort sequence](https://superuser.com/questions/190426/nautilus-copy-to-same-dir-name-gives-a-whacky-sort-sequence-copy-another-cop)

..and I won't even mention how the sorting algorithm completely ignores leading non-alphanumeric characters (like they don't exist).... oops, I just mentioned it :)

`nautilus` is significantly grafted into the desktop, and offers such features as auto mounting, and file/folder notes, so I put up with this sorting anomaly; I just name my files in accordance with this algorithm, ie zero-padded numbers, and no leading non-alphanumeric characters...

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an option in Nautilus or in the `gconf-editor`. I tried your problem with Nautilus, Dolphin, Thunar and LXDE Filemanager and only Dolphin (very KDE like) offeres the option.