# Rename multiple files sequentially and starting by the same prefix

Tags: command-line, scripts, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder containing like 1500 files, I want to rename them automatically via the terminal or a shell script as follows: "prefix_number.extension".
**Example:** cin_1.jpg, cin_2.png ...

Comment: Likely related: [Sequential renaming of files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679283/sequential-renaming-of-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```bsh
count=0; for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv -i "$f" "cin_$((++count)).${f##*.}"; done
```

Or, if you prefer your commands spread over multiple lines:

```bsh
count=0
for f in *
do
    [ -f "$f" ] && mv -i "$f" "cin_$((++count)).${f##*.}"
done
```

#### How it works

- `count=0`

  This initializes the variable `count` to zero.
- `for f in *; do`

  This starts a loop over all files in the current directory.
- `[ -f "$f" ] && mv -i "$f" "cin_$((++count)).${f##*.}"`

  `[ -f "$f" ]` tests to see if the file `$f` is a regular file (not a directory).

  If `$f` is a regular file, then the move (`mv`) command is run.  `-i` tells `mv` not to overwrite any existing files without asking.  `"cin_$((++count)).${f##*.}"` is the name of the new file.  `cin_` is the prefix.  `$((++count))` returns the value of `count` after it has been incremented.  `${f##*.}` is the extension of file `$f`.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the loop.

#### Example

Consider a directory with these three files:

```bsh
$ ls
alpha.jpg  beta.png  gamma.txt
```

Let's run our command:

```bsh
$ count=0; for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv -i "$f" "cin_$((++count)).${f##*.}"; done
```

After running our command, the files in the directory now are:

```bsh
$ ls
cin_1.jpg  cin_2.png  cin_3.txt
```

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted, and it is super fast (faster than with Python). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A `rename` oneliner:

```bsh
rename -n 's/.+\./our $i; sprintf("cin_%d.", 1+$i++)/e' *
```

This matches every file with a dot in its name (the last one, if multiple) and renames the part until the dot with `cin_` followed by an incrementing number and a dot. With the `-n` flag it just prints what it would do, remove it to perform the renaming.

#### Example run

```
$ ls
a.jpg  b.jpg  d.png  e.png
$ rename -n 's/.+\./our $i; sprintf("cin_%d.", 1+$i++)/e' *
rename(a.jpg, cin_1.jpg)
rename(b.jpg, cin_2.jpg)
rename(d.png, cin_3.png)
rename(e.png, cin_4.png)
$ rename 's/.+\./our $i; sprintf("cin_%d.", 1+$i++)/e' *
$ ls
cin_1.jpg  cin_2.jpg  cin_3.png  cin_4.png
```

Source: [How to rename multiple files sequentially from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/478197/507051)