# rename the last number-string

Tags: bash, batch-rename

How to rename the last number-string it finds with a zero-padded version and leave the rest of the filename alone?

```
AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_1.pdf
```

To:

```
AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_0001.pdf
```

See:

- [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473236/)
- [How to zero pad numbers in file names in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754/how-to-zero-pad-numbers-in-file-names-in-bash) (on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would probably be to match the preceding `page_` string

Ex:

```
$ rename -n 's/page_(\d+)/sprintf "page_%04d", $1/e' *.pdf
rename(AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_1.pdf, AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_0001.pdf)
```

(remove the `-n` when you are happy that it is doing the right thing).

---

If you *really* need to match the "last number", you could use *positive lookahead* to anchor the match to the end of the string `$` with a possibly empty sequence of non-digits between:

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d+)(?=\D*$)/sprintf "%04d", $1/e' *.pdf
rename(AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_1.pdf, AAA 2000-01-03 bbb 2001-03-04 page_0001.pdf)
```

Comment: thanks It works, but how would you do without the page as a reference?

Comment: @Rafael see edit