# zero padding of file names

Tags: command-line, mv

I want to do zero-padding for names of files. what should I do if not all images exist like 1.JPEG doesn't exist or 99.JPEG or 110.JPEG ?

```
 $ for n in $(seq 9); do mv $n.JPEG 0$n.JPEG; done; mv: cannot stat ‘1.JPEG’: No such file or directory
```

I do not want to rename manually because order of videos are important.

Comment: Maybe use `find` command and its `exec` ?

Comment: This answer [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/a/473355/178692) uses the Perl-based `rename` with a simple shell glob - that avoids having to *generate* filenames

Comment: Use "if" to check if the file exists. `for n in $(seq 9); do if [[ -f $n.JPEG ]]; then mv $n.JPEG 0$n.JPEG; fi done;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` inside the loop to check if the file exists. And if it does, then only `mv` operation would take place.

```bsh
for n in $(seq 9) 
do 
  if [[ -f $n.JPEG ]] 
  then 
       mv $n.JPEG 0$n.JPEG 
  fi 
done;
```

Or in one line:

```bsh
for n in $(seq 9); do if [[ -f $n.JPEG ]]; then mv $n.JPEG 0$n.JPEG; fi done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter expansion you can split the filename into name and extension, then glue them together with `printf` formatting

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *; do
    mv $i $(printf %04d.%s\\n ${i/./ })
done
```

printf formatting:

- `%04d` pad digit with four zeros.
- `%s`     String of characters.

${parameter/pattern/string}

- Pattern  substitution; parameter is expanded and  the  longest  match  of  pattern against its value is replaced with string.