# How to enumerate a variable in a loop starting at 01?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, programming, rename

I have a question

I have the rename command, but after I run the rename starting from 00, how to start from 01, please help me

this is the command that I use

```
for i in *.mkv; do
  new=$(printf "Movie - %02d.mkv" "$a")
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: Such kind of renaming could be easily done by using the command `rename`, here is a nice example: [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/a/473355/566421).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as adding a variable (`a=1`) at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
for i in *.mkv; do
  new=$(printf "Movie - %02d.mkv" "$a")
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Here is in one line as you asked for:

```
a=1; for i in *.mkv; do new=$(printf "Movie - %02d.mkv" "$a"); mv -i -- "$i" "$new"; let a=a+1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The same can be done with bash's [arithmetic evaluation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ARITHMETIC_EVALUATION), too. And [it's generally preferred over `let` builtin](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let#examples).

For exmaple,

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
for i in *.mkv; do
  new=$(printf "Movie - %02d.mkv" "$a")
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  ((a++))
done
```

On other hand, if you prefer a one-liner, `rename` command can do that:

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("Movie - %02d", $&)/e' *.mkv
```