# how mass rename files with the following syntax

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have about 130 images in the following syntax:

```
image100.jpeg
image101.jpeg
....
image1.jpeg
image20.jpeg
image21.jpeg
..
image2.jpeg
```

and so on.
I want rename with the following syntax because I want conver them into pdf.

```
image001.jpeg
image002.jpeg
...
image020.jpeg
image021.jpeg
...
image100.jpeg
```

how could I do it in bash ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473236/renaming-hundreds-of-files-at-once-for-proper-sorting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `rename` for this.

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e' image*
```