# Ubuntu Inbuilt Bulk File Rename Mask

Tags: batch-rename

is there a chance to edit file mask within Ubuntu inbuilt file renamer?
I need to name image files with 4 number format, img_1.jpeg needs to be renamed into img_0001.jpeg. Ubuntu offers only 3 number format img_001.jpg. Is there a way I could edit that? [Renamer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S25vX.png)
Thank you

Comment: If not, there are several good command line solutions - see for example [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473236/renaming-hundreds-of-files-at-once-for-proper-sorting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473236/renaming-hundreds-of-files-at-once-for-proper-sorting)